# jQuery: select all DIV's nested under specific DIV

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, cursor, mouseover

I have an architecture similar to this:

```
<div id="container">
<div>stuff here</div>
<div>stuff here</div>
<div>stuff here</div>
<div>stuff here</div>
</div>
```

I want to, using jQuery, hide the cursor when the mouse enters `#container`.  However as the nested divs appear on top it doesn't quite work that way.  How can I hide the mouse cursor when hovering over any of the divs within `#container`.  Below is the cursor hiding code.

```
        $('#container').mouseover(function()
        {
            $(this).css({cursor: 'none'});
        });
```

Comment: setting css cursor to 'none' does not work in Chrome, just FYI.

Comment: @jAndy How do you get around this in Chrome?

Comment: Why don't you use pure css for that? I'm sure you could achieve the same effect with the :hover pseudo class (except for IE 6)

Comment: I have actually just done this chiborg.  Which works perfectly except under Chrome :(

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have a solution for Chrome, just noticed the effect when executing some examples based on your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dare I say it, you could just target both parent and child divs?

```
$('#container, #container div').mouseover(function()
{
    $(this).css({cursor: 'none'});
});
```

Granted I haven't tested this, but had to use a similar method to change the cursor of a `<li>` with a `<label>` child.

You could extend this slightly using the [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) function.

Answer (score 3):

Although there are several correct answer, I think this is more efficient.

```
$('#container').mouseover(function(){
   $(this).children().andSelf().css('cursor', 'none');
});
```

This way you are only using one event listener, on the `#container`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#container > div').mouseover(function()
{
    $(this).css('cursor', 'none');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the children() selector.

```
$('#container').children().mouseover(function()
    {
        $(this).css({cursor: 'none'});
    });
```